# Can one prevent Genshi from parsing HTML entities?

Tags: python, html, entities, genshi

I have the following Python code using Genshi (simplified):

```
with open(pathToHTMLFile, 'r') as f:
    template = MarkupTemplate(f.read())
finalPage = template.generate().render('html', doctype = 'html')
```

The source HTML file contains entities such as `&copy;`, `&trade;` and `&reg;`.  Genshi replaces these with their UTF-8 character, which causes problems with the viewer (the output is used as a stand-alone file, not a response to a web request) that eventually sees the resulting HTML.  Is there any way to prevent Genshi from parsing these entities?  The more common ones like `&amp;` are passed through just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually `&amp;` isn't passed through, it's parsed into an ampersand character, and then serialised back to `&amp;` on the way out because that's necessary to represent a literal ampersand in HTML. `&copy;`, on the other hand, is not a necessary escape, so it can be left as its literal character.

So no, there's no way to *stop* the entity reference being parsed. But you can ensure that non-ASCII characters are re-escaped on the way back out by serialising to plain ASCII:

```
template.generate().render('html', doctype= 'html', encoding= 'us-ascii')
```

You still won't get the entity reference `&copy;` in your output, but you will get the character reference `&#169;` which is equivalent and should hopefully be understood by whatever is displaying the final file.

Answer (score 3):

Sticking

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in the `<head>` of your HTML should cause browsers to correctly render UTF-8.

To clarify, the root issue is that the corresponding © UTF-8 character does not render correctly in static HTML. Placing the meta tag in the HTML tells the browser how to correctly interpret the character set and thus renders the UTF-8 characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent escaping of (x)html markup characters in Genshi:

```
from genshi.core import Markup
...
newstring = Markup(oldstring)
...
<now apply templates as before, but substituting newstring for oldstring>
```